# Using grants while on unpaid leave

Tags: funding

When a professor goes on unpaid leave from her university, can she normally continue to use her grants to fund graduate students and postdocs?  Or, do all grants "freeze" until the professor returns?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't see any reason that a professor wouldn't be able to continue to use grants while on leave.  In fact, I'm on unpaid leave from my home institution right now, and have been able to use my grants (for travel support for myself), so that's one data point.

Comment: I'll add another "yes" data point. Unless the leave is disciplinary, I've never known an institute to freeze grants. And, often the leave is granted to give time specifically to work on projects supported by grants.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Would this still be true even if the professor was on unpaid leave because she was planning to leave her university?

Comment: @anonymous555 Why not?  I think they still need to have an official appointment, but I think even 0% appointment (one with no pay) suffices.  It's possible that if the university really wanted to, maybe they could find some way to do this, but why on earth would they?  The PI would just transfer the grants and they wouldn't get the overhead.

Answer (score 10):

The answer is "yes".  For instance, I was on unpaid leave this academic year, and used my grant to support a graduate student.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the breakdown of the grant. If there are students or staff who were hired to do the proposed work then I don't see any reason why they wouldn't continue being paid if they are continuing to work. The same goes for research related services and products. Sometimes sabbaticals are unpaid, but that doesn't mean that the work stops. Most grants are on a schedule, so PIs need to be making some form of progress on the project (whether or not they are getting paid from it).